# HTML variable inside of String

Tags: html, django, string, variables

I'm building a website with Django. I want to have a string url [already done], but I want the string to be changeable based on variables.

sudocode:
variable a = "Hello"

url = "www.facebook.com/a" ----> I want the "a" to be changeable, so if it changes, the url goes to a different website.

What is the best way to do this?

thanks

Comment: url = "www.facebook.com/" + a ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [saving groups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls) in your `urls.py`:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<part>\w*)/$', 'my_app.views.my_view'),
)
```

Then, in your `my_view` view the string will appear as a keyword argument:

```
def my_view(request, part=None):
    print part
```

Hope that helps.